# Snowflake Dynamic query to run the sql from another table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table which contains id and query and I need to test If the query is executable. For that I can manually use Explain plan but I need to do it dynamically since they are in 1000.

Table sample

```
id   | script
 1   | Select current_date();
 2   | Select current_timestamps();
 3   | Select * from t1 where t1 > 1000;
 4   | select * from t2 where date < current_date();
```

Please notice id 3 is wrong.

So I am writing a JavaScript procedure which will execute and return all the ids whose script is wrong.

I have created the below stored procedure which will take the query from one table and execute it. And I am trying to return all the wrong ids in comma separated string.

Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure TestQuery (table_name VARCHAR,column_name1 string,column_name2 string)
    returns string 
    not null
    language javascript
    as
    $$
    var op = "";
    // Dynamically compose the SQL statement to execute.
    var sqlCommand = "select " + COLUMN_NAME1 + "," + COLUMN_NAME2 + " from " + TABLE_NAME;
    // Prepare statement.
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
           {
           sqlText: sqlCommand
           }
        );
    // Execute Statement
    var res = stmt.execute();
    while (res.next())  {
        v_col_name = res.getColumnValue(2);
        sqlcommand2 = "explain using tabular " + v_col_name
        var stmt2 = snowflake.createStatement(
           {
           sqlText: sqlcommand2
           }
        );
        var res2 = stmt2.execute();
        while (res2.next())  {
            try{
                //do nothing
                }
            catch{
            op = op + "," + res.getColumnValue(1);
                }
            }
        }
    if (op = "") {
    return "all success"
    }    
    else {
    return op}    
    $$;
```

The procedure is working fine but not as I intend it to.
On the very first error script it is throwing error and coming out of procedure itself. How can I record the error query and move to next one. Seems I am missing something in try and catch.

Can anybody please suggest what I am missing here.

Comment: You need to execute stmt2

Comment: @NickW Thank you for suggestion. I added the stmt2 and procedure is working fine but not as I intend it to ... Rather than catching the sql error and moving it to next one. The procedure is failing all together.

Comment: Hi - I think you need the try round the stmt2.execute() part as that is presumably the line that is erroring, rather than when you are trying to loop through the results from executing this statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the `try` block was in the wrong place. There were some other errors. For example, when comparing values in JavaScript, use `==` or `===`. Using `=` is only for assignments and evaluates incorrectly inside `if` expressions.

```
create or replace transient table T1 (ID int, SQL_TEXT string, SQL_NAME string);

insert into T1 (ID, SQL_TEXT, SQL_NAME) values
 (1,'Select current_date();', 'Test1'),
 (2,'Select current_timestamps();', 'Test2'),
 (3,'Select * from foobar10384 where t1 > 1000;', 'Test3'),
 (4,'select * from t2 where date < current_date();', 'Test4');
 
 
 create or replace procedure TestQuery (TABLE_NAME string, SQL_TEXT string, SQL_NAME string)
    returns string 
    not null
    language javascript
    as
    $$
    var op = "";
    // Dynamically compose the SQL statement to execute.
    var sqlCommand = `select ${SQL_TEXT}, ${SQL_NAME} from ${TABLE_NAME}`;
    // Prepare statement.
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
           {
           sqlText: sqlCommand
           }
        );
    // Execute Statement
    
    var res = stmt.execute();

    while (res.next())  {
        v_col_name = res.getColumnValue("SQL_TEXT");
        sqlcommand2 = "explain using tabular " + v_col_name
        var stmt2 = snowflake.createStatement(
           {
           sqlText: sqlcommand2
           }
        );
        try {
             var res2 = stmt2.execute();
        } catch (err) {
             if (op != "") op += ",";
             op += res.getColumnValue("SQL_NAME");
        }
    }
    if (op == "") {
    return "all success"
    }    
    else {
    return op}    
    $$;    

call testquery('T1', 'SQL_TEXT', 'SQL_NAME');
```

Edit with a final thought: Since this is going through the work of identifying bad SQL, it should return the reason it's bad. This refactor returns an array. The array will be empty if there are no SQL errors. It will be filled with one or more objects containing the name of the SQL with an error and the error itself:

```
 create or replace procedure TestQuery (TABLE_NAME string, SQL_TEXT string, SQL_NAME string)
    returns array 
    not null
    language javascript
    as
    $$
    var op = [];
    var err = {};
    // Dynamically compose the SQL statement to execute.
    var sqlCommand = `select ${SQL_TEXT}, ${SQL_NAME} from ${TABLE_NAME}`;
    // Prepare statement.
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
           {
           sqlText: sqlCommand
           }
        );
    // Execute Statement
    
    var res = stmt.execute();

    while (res.next())  {
        v_col_name = res.getColumnValue("SQL_TEXT");
        sqlcommand2 = "explain using tabular " + v_col_name
        var stmt2 = snowflake.createStatement(
           {
           sqlText: sqlcommand2
           }
        );
        try {
             var res2 = stmt2.execute();
        } catch (e) {
             err = {};
             err.SQL_NAME = res.getColumnValue("SQL_NAME");
             err.SQL_ERROR = e.message;
             op.push(err);
        }
    }
    return op
    $$;
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "SQL_ERROR": "SQL compilation error:\nUnknown function CURRENT_TIMESTAMPS",
    "SQL_NAME": "Test2"
  },
  {
    "SQL_ERROR": "SQL compilation error:\nObject 'FOOBAR10384' does not exist or not authorized.",
    "SQL_NAME": "Test3"
  },
  {
    "SQL_ERROR": "SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 45\ninvalid identifier 'DATE'",
    "SQL_NAME": "Test4"
  }
]
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for all your effort and stating it so clearly..